# rake db:create creates test database, not development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am creating database with `rake db:create`

But it creates a `test database`, not a `development database`.

I have set a database environment as `development` but it doesn't help.

Have anyone had this issue before?

Comment: What's in your config/database.yml? Try passing the env right in the command (`RAILS_ENV=development ...`).

Comment: @SebastianPalma, what is the difference between rake db:create vs rails db:create?

Comment: As far as I know, nothing. There was a time where certain tasks were handled by the rake and others by the rails binary respectively. Then that was "unified" so, you should be able to run the tasks in both ways.